# AWS Spot Fleet Request cannot start instances because of failed tagging

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam

I've got a spot fleet request. I'm getting an error every few minutes when it tries to start an instance, so it is completely crippled, and does nothing:

```
{
    "allowed": false,
    "explicitDeny": false,
    "matchedStatements": {
        "items": []
    },
    "failures": {
        "items": []
    },
    "context": {
        "principal": {
            "id": "ARARARARARARARARARARAR:45454545-f05e-4545-a756-45454545",
            "arn": "arn:aws:sts::034566890123:assumed-role/AWSServiceRoleForEC2SpotFleet/45454545-f05e-4545-a756-45454545"
        },
        "action": "ec2:CreateTags",
        "resource": "arn:aws:ec2:ap-southeast-2:034566890123:network-interface/*",
...
```

From this error, we see that I don't have permission to create tags on network interfaces. This is an issue, since my launch template asks for that.

The SFR has a "IAM fleet role": aws-ec2-spot-fleet-tagging-role, which is an autogenerated one, but not an AWS builtin.

Apparently, *supposedly*, I automatically get the AWSServiceRoleForEC2SpotFleet role, which is where the error is coming from.

**AWSEC2SpotFleetServiceRolePolicy** (DEFAULT, AUTOMATIC, AND UNABLE TO BE EDITED/MODIFIED):

```
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:CreateTags"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:instance/*",
                "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:spot-instances-request/*",
                "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:spot-fleet-request/*",
                "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:volume/*"
            ]
        },
```

Clearly, I cannot create tags.
Thankfully we're adding them with our other role, which we actually have a choice for:

**aws-ec2-spot-fleet-tagging-role** (AUTO-GENERATED, BUT I CAN ACTUALLY CHOOSE THIS):

```
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:DescribeImages",
                "ec2:DescribeSubnets",
                "ec2:RequestSpotInstances",
                "ec2:TerminateInstances",
                "ec2:DescribeInstanceStatus",
                "ec2:CreateTags",  <<----------
                "ec2:RunInstances"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "*"   <<----------
            ]
```

Ahh yes, perfect. It's all coming together. It seems like these default settings, automatically created and selected by AWS, should work together in harmony.

They will both be taken into consideration, and we will be able to tag anything, because I assume these permissions are additive, otherwise it would be impossible to ever tag a network instance and surely that's not a thing.

So my SFR has:

```
IAM fleet role: aws-ec2-spot-fleet-tagging-role
                (and technically, also AWSEC2SpotFleetServiceRolePolicy)
```

So then why, oh why, do I get this error?

How can I fix this?

Please, explain how my permissions under `aws-ec2-spot-fleet-tagging-role`, which should be the IAM role that I chose myself, and is the ONLY ONE I HAVE CONTROL OVER, is not being applied?

---

Bonus information:

- This works perfectly if my config template isn't tagging network interfaces.
- I have not created or changed any of the IAM roles. They're all auto-generated, default, or otherwise normal
- Here is an image, as proof of the role which I have on the "Spot Requests" page
- Here is another image, to show the launch template options I have. Weirdly, it doesn't show the network interfaces selection on this...
- Third image, of what I did when editing the launch template. It still shows this if I try to edit it further.
- I am not using elastic graphics, as far as I know? It's a very basic setup, normal stuff.

[image: proof]

[image: more proof]

[image: further proof]

Comment: Does your user have `ec2:CreateTags` for `"*"`? Apparently, there is a [limitation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/work-with-spot-fleets.html#tag-spot-fleet-prereqs) that the resource must be `"*"`.